# Summary of Data.frame with Lubridate Duration

Tags: r, duration, lubridate

I am using lubridate-Durations to store the duration of a video.

I get the following error if i call summary(video):

```
    Error in sprintf("%ds (~%s %ss)", x, x2, unit, "s)") : 
     invalid format '%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

The `str(videos)` says:

```
  $ DURATION              :Formal class 'Duration' [package "lubridate"] with 1 slot
   .. ..@ .Data: num  602 760 1027 714 720 .
```

is there a way to fix this? Using lubridate with the same functions like mean, top ect. like for numeric values would be nice.

The error occures only with a data.frame of size 1250 and higher

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed with the developer's version of lubridate.

Check out: https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/commit/faf336770917f8cb624789f11bf01e12090d838f

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not reproducible, here is my code I used.

```
set.seed(1)

DURATION = lubridate::dminutes(
  sample(0:300, 2000, replace = T)
) 

videos <- data.frame(
  DURATION = DURATION
)

str(videos)
# 'data.frame': 2000 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ DURATION:Formal class 'Duration' [package "lubridate"] with 1 slot
#  .. ..@ .Data: num  4740 6720 10320 16380 3600 ...

summary(videos)
#    DURATION                   
# Min.   :0s                    
# 1st Qu.:4320s (~1.2 hours)    
# Median :8700s (~2.42 hours)   
# Mean   :8909s (~2.47 hours)   
# 3rd Qu.:13620s (~3.78 hours)  
# Max.   :18000s (~5 hours)
```

Comment: it seems, that the problem is the size of the data.frame. If you use 2000 samples instead of 5, you will get the same error?

It's funny because my testset contains 1255 Videos, with a subset of 1250 it runs fine, but with 5 more i get the error (the last 5 videos does not differ from the rest)

Any explanation?

Comment: I have edited my code. When you use `as.numeric()`the error is gone.

Comment: The error is gone, but the problem is not solved, because you are not using the Formal class Duration anymore.

I have stored DURATION in seconds in my database, and convert it to lubridate's Duration in R using `dseconds()`. Calling as.numeric is a fallback to the situation before.

Comment: dminutes(x) stores a duration with x minutes, that is not what i want. The workaround with dminutes(x/60) leads to the same error 

I think, there is a bug in lubridate.